# How to have multiple HTML templates for same Component Class without using ngIf in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Data for all child is same ,but the view differs .i know this can be achieved using **ngIf** .but since the HTML lines are more it needs to be in seperate file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can (almost) achieve the same thing by using `<ng-content></ng-content>` like so, for example `MyComp` is the dynamic templated component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class MyComp { ... }
```

Now you can drop anything inside `<my-comp>`

```
<app-root>

  <my-comp>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </my-comp>

  <my-comp>
    <div>Angular is awesome</div>
  </my-comp>

</app-root>
```

Comment: But that deoes'nt seperate files right. the main intent is to have seperate HTML & CSS files.

Comment: True. But you can have a global style for them. There is no way to achieve multiple templates per component

Comment: ok..does inheritance help this case...can we inherit the properties child class from parent ?!

Comment: Absolutely. You can let the child classes inherit any protected and public properties declared in the parent class, you **can't** inherit metadata from the parent class however

Comment: Alright there is a object in Parent class... can we access that object in child class ?!

Comment: As long as it is not private, you will inherit it